# How to make array list in my case using Batch File Script?

Tags: batch-file, windows-scripting

I want to copy files from one folder to multiple pc in the local network.

I want to add IP address in array list like below

```
set list=\\192.168.55.102
set list=%list%;\\192.168.55.103 
set list=%list%;\\192.168.55.104 
set list=%list%;\\192.168.55.105
set list=%list%;\\192.168.55.106
```

then, I will copy file to above IP's by following code. But the following code will do for 1 ip. It's working and copied the file to destination location

```
net use "\\192.168.55.102\c$\foldername" /user:%username% %password%
:copy
copy "C:\Desktop\Update" "\\192.168.55.102\c$\foldername"
IF ERRORLEVEL 0 goto disconnect
goto end
:disconnect 
net use "\\192.168.55.102\c$\foldername" /delete
goto end
:end
```

I tried like below, but it doesn't work

```
@echo off
for %a% in (%list%) do (  
    net use %a%\foldername /user:%username% %password%
    :copy
    copy "C:\Desktop\Update" %a%\foldername
    IF ERRORLEVEL 0 goto disconnect
    goto end
    :disconnect 
    net use %a%\foldername /delete
    goto end
    :end
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a variable (not array) and add the IP's separated by space, comma or semicolon. Then connect to `IPC$` to allow authentication, copy the file(s) and then remove the `IPC$` share:

```
@echo off
set "list=192.168.55.102 192.168.55.103 192.168.55.104 192.168.55.105 192.168.55.106"
for %%i in (%list%) do (
    net use "\\%%i\IPC$" /user:%username% %password%
    copy "C:\Desktop\Update" "\\%%i\foldername"
    net use /d "\\%%i\IPC$"
)
```